# Using sequence-type functions with lists from user input

Tags: python

I am currently writing a program where user user would input a list of cities they have lived in. Next the code will return the number of cities they have lived in. I am having trouble generating the number of cities the user has lived in. I am using len(). Below is my code.

```py
#stores the user input in a string call myfirst_string
myfirst_string = (input("Hello, What is your name: "))

#Returns the first 2 letters of the user's name
print("The first two letters of your name is: ", myfirst_string[0] + myfirst_string[1])

#stores the lists of cities where the user has lived into a variable call places_lived_list
places_lived_list = [input("Which cities have you lived in: ")]

#outputs the cities the user has lived in and then returns the number of cities lived in based on the cities the user has input and are separated by commas.
print("You have lived in these cities: ",places_lived_list)
print("you have lived in", len(places_lived_list), 'City')
```

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVJWb.png)

Comment: The first line doesn't need the parentheses, the second line doesn't 'return' something, it prints it (that's not the same, and an important distinction), the third line asks the user for a single line of input and stores the returned string in a list (as the only element). There's only 1 string, so the length is 1. You want to `.split()` a string if the cities are separated by spaces.

Comment: Please use standard formatting on your code, don't try to make it 'pretty'; also consider [why you should not upload images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Grismar What do you mean by the first line doesn't need the parentheses? If I remove all of the parentheses, from my first_string = (input("Hello, what is your name: ") the code will not run. 

For the second line, I am not sure I am following. Are you saying I should change it? (Sorry I am still new at this)

How would the syntax for .split() look like with len()? Would it be len().split(,)?

Comment: I've answered your original question and the ones in the comments below.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful! Additionally, thank you for providing me further guidance on the dos and don'ts when posting questions here! Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome - if you're happy with the answer below (mine, or DinosaurMoritz' short and to the point one), please select the checkmark next to it, so that your question no longer appears as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The third line should be somthing like:

```
places_lived_list = input("Which cities have you lived in: ").split(",")
```

Note that this only works if the cities are provided in the format "city1,city2,city3"

Answer (score 0):

You asked a few follow-up questions in the comments, here's your code with some corrections and the problem resolved:

```
# no parentheses required around the call to `input`
myfirst_string = input('Hello, What is your name: ')

# nothing is returned here, the string is indexed twice and print 
# technically returns `None`, but this isn't captured
print("The first two letters of your name is:", myfirst_string[0] + myfirst_string[1])

# here's the answer
places_lived_list = input('Which cities have you lived in (with commas): ').split(',')

# still a list
print('You have lived in these cities:', places_lived_list)

# so the length is correct
print('You have lived in', len(places_lived_list), 'cities')
```

You were also using both `'` and `"` to delimit your strings, it's generally best to pick one and `'` is the Python default.

Running the script now:

```
Hello, What is your name: Grismar
The first two letters of your name is: Gr
Which cities have you lived in (with commas): Den Haag, Brisbane
You have lived in these cities: ['Den Haag', ' Brisbane']
You have lived in 2 cities
```